# React Native: for installing Expo module, should I install expo with `npm install` and then the module with `npx expo install`?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, expo, npx

In my React Native app, I need to install `expo-modules-core` and `expo-mail-composer`. I want to make sure I'm installing versions that are compatible with my existing project. Should I run `npm i expo` and `npm i install-expo-modules`, and then `npx expo expo-modules-core` and `npx expo expo-mail-composer`?

Comment: I think you want something like `expo install`.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to install

> expo-module-core
> where on your react application or your react native application
> all you need to do is

```
npm install expo-module-core
```